# Left joining right aligned field with left aligned field in Crystal

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I have a report where I need to join two tables but the fields are defined differently between them and I cannot change the table schemas because its JDEdwards.   So I have one field as 30 characters left aligned and another another as 12 characters right aligned.  The values will always be under 12 characters.  So the issue is not the difference in size but the alignment/padding.   I have to do a left join though.  Right now the report is just comparing in the data selection and causing an inner join.  But I need to change it to left join to stop losing rows.  Is there any way to do it?

What happens is when I create the link to do the left join in Database Expert, I end up getting the data from the joined table all blank due to it not finding any rows because of the padding difference.

Comment: You can use left join using link options. Have you tried that?

Comment: @Siva, Yes. But as I mention, one of the fields is padded left and the other padded right, so that doesn't work.

Comment: Do you need access to many fields from this join? If not, you could manually create a subquery via SQL Expression and bypass adding the table to your report (via the Database Expert) at all. Or you could create a SQL Command and do the entire report in a manually created query.

Comment: @Ryan, I only need one field. I have to join this just to get a description of the next step in the routing of a WO.  I think doing a subquery via SQL Expression sounds like the way to go, but I don't know how to do that. I'd have to be able to do the whole query there since this table won't be related in any way to the main query because I can't join it in Database Expert.

Comment: You wouldn't need to do a join in the Database Expert with the SQL Expression. You would be able to use any valid SQL to create the subquery and then relate it back to your main report in the WHERE-clause.

Answer (score 1):

Since you only need one value from the table to be joined you can instead create a single SQL Expression to get the value for you without the need to add any tables to the report itself via Database Expert. You'll be able to use any valid SQL so you can do pretty much whatever you want without being constrained by Crystal.

For example, say your report consists of Table_A with a foreign key that is 30-characters left-aligned and you're trying to join to Table_B to get at some field, but that key is 12 characters right-aligned. A simple example in Oracle would be something like this:

```
case when "Table_A"."ForeignKey" is null then null
else
 (select Table_B.SomeFieldYouWant
  from Table_B
  where rpad(Table_B.PrimaryKey,30,'0')="Table_A"."ForeignKey"
end
```

It's important to note that in a SQL Expression, any fields referenced with double quotes means that it's referring back to tables/fields in your report instead of new tables in the subquery; this is how you relate the subquery back to your report's data.

Comment: Opps, I just figured out I put this in the Formula Field section instead of SQL Expressions...trying again....